# jQuery repeater show/hide element on the dropdown change

Tags: jquery, repeater

I am using jQuery Repeater. My design is like the following:

```
Dropdown 1  Text 1   Text Area 1   Office
Dropdown 2  Text 2   Text Area 2   Office
```

A repeater is working very fine. But Now I want to show/hide "Other Element" depending on the value of the Dropdown.

I have tried the following code. It is working only of the first row not for every row inside the repeater.

```
$("[data-repeater-list=iorder_data] [name=authority]").on('change', function(){


        if ($(this).val() == 1 )
        {
            $('#office').show();

        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 2)
        {
            $('#office').hide();
        }

    });
```

Please help me where and what I've missed.

Thanks

Comment: You just can't use two attribute selectors at once.

Comment: `$("[data-repeater-list=iorder_data] [name=authority]")` should be `$("[data-repeater-list=iorder_data]")` and in an each() loop, check if it also is a `$("[name=authority]")`. Then define the handler on the matching elements. --- This said.. There is possibly another way too. Can't tell with so few code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear to me what you want to do, but if your dropdown has both attributes (data-repeater-list=iorder_data AND [name=authority]), you should remove the space in the selector:

```
$("[data-repeater-list=iorder_data][name=authority]").on('change', function(){
```

Edit: after reading other comments, I think this is what you want:

```
$("[data-repeater-list=iorder_data]").each(function() { 
    $(this).find("[name=authority]").on('change', function() {
        // your code (check values)
    });
}
```